# How can I remove rows of a dataframe that contain two specific characters?

Tags: r, filter

I have a character column of a dataframe that contains 7 letters that are either A,B,C,D.

for example

1 - AAAABBB
2 - ACBCDAB
3 - AACCADD
4 - ACDCACC
5 - ABAABBC
6 - BCBBDCB

I would like to remove rows of the dataframe that contain both an A and B,
but keep any rows that contain A's, C's, D's or B's, C's, D's

So the end result should be.

3 - AACCADD
4 - ACDCACC
6 - BCBBDCB

The number of A's and B's in a cell do not matter, as long as the cell has at least both one A and one B I would like to remove that row.

I've tried to use str_split_fix and then subset the various columns, but I feel like there should be a more efficient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With base R

```
subset(your_data, !(grepl("A", your_column) & grepl("B", your_column)))
```

Or with tidyverse

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
your_data |> 
  filter(!(str_detect(your_column, "A") & str_detect(your_column, "B"))
```